# VS Code CSS Configuration Preview Not Working With Markdown Workspace Settings

Tags: css, sass, markdown, visual-studio-code

## Issue

**CSS** styling is not displaying in the the *VS Code* preview for Markdown files despite being configured under the *Workspace Settings* per the *VS Code* documentation [Extending the Markdown preview](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/markdown#_extending-the-markdown-preview).

## Expected

Here is how the published Markdown file *media.md* displays when being hosted.

*Note: Green border added to highlight Markdown code.*

[image]

## Result

Here is how the Markdown file *media.md* displays in the VS Code preview.

*Note: Green border added to highlight Markdown code.*

[image]

## Setup

### Workspace Structure

The Markdown file attempting to be styled with *assets/css/style.scss* is *media.md*.

[image]

### Workspace Settings

This is configured under *Workspace Settings* as opposed to *User Settings*.

```
{
    "markdown.styles": [
        "assets/css/style.scss"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[It looks like](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/markdown#_using-your-own-css) the `"markdown.styles": []` setting of VSC is particularly for CSS, not SCSS.

You can use [Sass](https://sass-lang.com/) to process your `*.scss` into `*.css` files that the VSC Markdown preview will be able to understand.

From the looks of it, though, it seems you're working on a Jekyll site (I see a `_config.yml` Jekyll configuration file). In that case, [serving your Jekyll site locally](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-your-github-pages-site-locally-with-jekyll/) to preview changes may be a better option.

---

*P.S. it would be easier to parse your question if the Markdown screenshots had a border around them to better differentiate between them and the details of the question itself :)*

Comment: Thanks for the pro-tip! I've added a border to differentiate the Markdown from the question. I will look into *serving Jekyll locally.*

Comment: Converting the **scss** to **css** with **sass** looks enticing as well. I'll report back on both fronts.